# Assigning Day Ranks With Missing Days

Tags: r, datetime, calendar, dplyr, rank

I have a **time series** in my data set:

```
ts <- c("2014-12-02", "2014-12-02", "2014-12-03", "2014-12-03", "2014-12-03","2014-12-05", "2014-12-05", "2014-12-05", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-03")
```

I would like to create a new variable **day rank** (dayrank) which assigns the first day the value of 1 and preserves the day rank even when some days are not observed (i.e., accounts for missing days in the data).

The desired output should look like this:

```
ts, dayrank

2014-12-02, 1
2014-12-02, 1
2014-12-03, 2
2014-12-03, 2
2014-12-05, 4
2014-12-05, 4
2015-01-01, 31
2015-01-01, 31
2015-01-03, 33
2015-01-03, 33
```

I have tried `min_rank` and `dense_rank` from dplyr, but they are unable to produce the required result.

Is there an existing method available for this task? Thank You for any suggestions.

Comment: Does `2017-02-01` return 32?

Comment: If it is observed, yes.

Comment: Its not a duplicate since the day of the year count will not preserve the calender rank across several years.

Comment: Can you make an example with such problem? Because with a given data it's a duplicate.

Comment: I updated the example